# How many documents have been co-authored?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, auditing, co-authoring

I need to prove that collaboration is happening.
One suggestion is to use measure the number of documents which have been co-authored in the past month.
Does anyone know how to do this ? I've been searching for powershell properties that might give some indication but come up with nothing.

To be clear I don't need to know how many documents can be co-authored, but rather how many have had multiple authors. Ideally I would also be able to show the names of the staff who did the co-authoring.

For those wanting to know environment : lets assume SharePoint 2013 on premise, multiple sites each with multiple libraries and a total of 10,000 documents that could be co-authored.

Thanks for your help.
Dorje

Comment: you can implement  SPAudit class for/ auditing functionality to track who modifies the document. you need to go with custom code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Audit feature to get a trace of every user interaction with documents. The event of your interest would be "Edit Item" or "Checking out and Checking in documents". You could read more [here](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.in/2013/07/audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2013.html).

Since I have personally never had the opportunity to work with these reports, you might need to explore further.

Another approach to look for could be catching item updated events in an event receiver, and logging the data into a database (or SharePoint list). But in my opinion that is an overkill.

Comment: Nisarg, thanks for that suggestion. I'd forgotten about the audit logs.
I was hoping someone would know of a powershell way of reading a document property that held the information about the number of users who have edited the document.
That way I could run the report on a regular basis and look back further than 30 or 90 days in the Audit logs.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a property that holds the list of users who have edited a document?